# any way to terminate a hex entry without using a space

Tags: c, non-ascii-characters, keil

KEIL 9.55

This works:

```
unsigned char code ID_Data_02[9]="\x02 1234567";
```

but what I really want is:

```
unsigned char code ID_Data_02[8]="\x021234567";
```

in the first case I just transmit using `*(p+0)`, followed by `*(p+2)` and ignore the white space that is delineating the hex vs ASCII component.

Anyone know something tidier?

K&R defines `\x` to indicate 1 or more hex `char`s - tried `\2x02` - seems like it's assumed the hex continues indefinitely until and non-`0`to`F` is encountered.

Comment: The `code` thing looks very much out of place.

Comment: As mentioned in answers, neither of your two arrays is a string, because there was no room for the compiler to include a `nul` terminator.

Comment: I thought it was great that you tried `"\2x1234"` for `"\x12” "34"`.

Answer (score 5):

Make use of string concatenation

```
unsigned char code ID_Data_02[8] = "\x02" "1234567";
```

Note that `ID_Data_02` is **not** a string: it does not have space for the terminating zero byte. Using it with most `str`* functions invokes UB.

Answer (score 3):

ANSI C concatenates adjacent strings into a single string so

```
unsigned char code ID_Data_02[8]="\x02" "1234567";
```

does what you want

Comment: Just barely beat me... :)  Correct.